# Using Twilio StatusCallback when a call on queue hangs up

Tags: api, callback, twilio

I'm implementing a Twilio-powered Call Center and I'm currently using Enqueue to hold calls until an operator can answer them. I'd like to use StatusCallback to warn operators that a call that was on hold is now "completed" (caller terminated the call) but StatusCallback seems only to work with a "Client" verb. I'd want to use it with along with "Enqueue" or a "Gather" in the WaitURL.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I found that setting the StatusCallback endpoint in the Application configuration in the Twilio [Dashboard](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/voice/dev-tools/api-explorer/call-create) globally solves this.